# Keyword GO throws errors with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux, sql-server-2005

I've come across a problem where I am trying to restore MSSQL dumps in php on a linux server. I'm am reading in a file and then passing the file in as a query.

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[recipes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Desc] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Directions] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CompAuthor] [nvarchar](500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CompName] [nvarchar](500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Servings] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_recipes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
```

BUT as soon as I add n a word like GO

```
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
    )

GO
```

It throws an error like

```
Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'
```

My question is what causes this error and how is it fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GO` is not a Transact-SQL keyword. It is a batch separator for tools like Management Studio and SQLCMD.

The answer is to not inject `GO` commands into the batches you are sending from your application. Just send them as separate batches (if necessary).

Source: [GO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

Comment: @Marek no that's fine. At first I was confused why it was an edit and not a comment.

Comment: Is there a way to do SQL dumps without GO?

Comment: @Marek understood, I said *at first*.

Comment: @Devin what are "SQL dumps"? Maybe your question should include the actual code you're trying to run, so we have some context on why you think `GO` is needed.

Comment: @Aaron , Dumps, a back up of a database its tables with constraints and their data.

Comment: @Devin how are you generating this? Again, can you show us what this looks like, so we have some idea if / why `GO` is even required?

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes you have scripts that were intended for deployment via Management Studio or Query Analyzer.

In my case, I'm managing several servers and deploying scripts could be tedious so I had to create a PHP tool that will automatically deploy to all servers.  Here's what I did to overcome that 'GO' problem:

```
    // split the script into several statements
    $sqls = explode("GO",$sql);

    // execute each statement separately
    foreach($sqls as $sqlb)
    {       
        $rs = mssql_query($sqlb, $mssql);

        if (!$rs) {
            echo "MSSQL {$client} sql: {$sqlb} Error: " . mssql_get_last_message();
        } else {

            if($rs === true)
            {
                echo "OK";
            } else
            {
                while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                    print_r($row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```